# Does it make sense? If yes then how to handle in MSE?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression, data-analysis

Can we do log transform to one variable and sqrt to another for LinearRegression? If yes then what to do during MSE? Should I exp or square the y_test and prediction?

```
boston['medv_log'] = np.log(boston.medv)
boston['lstat_sqrt'] = np.sqrt(boston.lstat)
x = boston.lstat_sqrt
y = boston.medv_log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform variables in training and test sets you don't need to care about your evaluation metric. In case you transform your target variable (with the `log` function for example) you need to transform your predictions (with the `exp` function) to get a real value.